# Controlling architecture in resulting RPM's

Tags: yocto, bitbake

I am trying to build all the recipes I made for my target architecture for my host systems architecture (x86_64), with the intention of being able to install these RPM's in x86_64 environments.

To do this I simply set `MACHINE=genericx86-64` and build; however, the resulting RPM's seem to have their architecture set to `core2_64`. I guess it is related to the `TUNE_FEATURES="m64 core2"` reported when running bitbake (see below).

How can I make sure that these RPM's end up as x86_64 so that my host (RHEL7) accepts them?

```
Build Configuration:
BB_VERSION        = "1.34.0"
BUILD_SYS         = "x86_64-linux"
NATIVELSBSTRING   = "universal-4.8"
TARGET_SYS        = "x86_64-poky-linux"
MACHINE           = "genericx86-64"
DISTRO            = "generic-panel"
DISTRO_VERSION    = "0.7"
TUNE_FEATURES     = "m64 core2"
TARGET_FPU        = ""
```

Example

```
# rpm -i xxx.core2_64.rpm
package xxx.core2_64 is intended for a different architecture

$ uname -a
Linux localhost 3.10.0-693.2.2.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Sat Sep 9 03:55:24 EDT 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Can I suggest not doing this? The RPMs are not guaranteed to be compatible with or safe to install on RHEL (or any other distro than the one you are creating with Yocto)  even if you make the arch into something rpm accepts.

Comment: @jku thanks for the heads up. What makes them inappropriate to use with RHEL? Also, do you have any suggestion for alternatives?

Comment: Well, I'm not saying it definitely won't work but packages make assumptions about the OS and other packages. There's no guarantees that even the package names used by Yocto and RHEL match (so your package might depend on a package that isn't found on RHEL because the name is different), let alone the functionality of the packages. It's a question of two different operating systems that happen to use the same package format.

Comment: The idea is to build the x86_64 packages with a different prefix under `/opt`, and use a localized pkgconfig to find the libraries. Do you see any concerns in that setup?

Comment: That definitely limits the things that could go wrong. Still, if your app dynamically links to any system libraries you could end up finding all kinds of incompatibilities -- but it might just work as well

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to modify the `DEFAULTTUNE` variable, so i just added `DEFAULTTUNE_genericx86-64 = "x86-64"` to my `local.conf`.